# How to make a button display stuff i enter in the input box on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm learning a bit of HTML nothing too deep. Basically i made a page with an input box and a button. What i want to do is make it so whatever i type in the input box displays on the page after i press the button. What code do i use?

this is part of my code:

```
  <body>

 <form>
  <input type="text">
</form>

    <div id="container">
    <button onclick="text()" id="button">Enter</button>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: `function text() { const value = document.querySelector('input').value; if (document.querySelector('p') != null) { document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;'); } else { let p = document.createElement('p'); p.innerHTML = value.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;'); document.body.appendChild(p); } }`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of input using `value` property and can use `textContent` to set the text into any HTML element.

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const output = document.querySelector(".output");

function text() {
  output.textContent = input.value;
};
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>

<div id="container">
  <button onclick="text()" id="button">Enter</button>
  <h1 class="output"></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `id` to your input and then I would do one of two things:

```js
<input type="text" id="text_box">
```

this -

```html
<script>

function text() {

alert(Document.getElementById('text_box').text)

}

</script>
```

or -

```html
<script>

function text() {

document.write(Document.getElementById('text_box').text)

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, there's no the "right" indeed.

- Better practice put the button inside the `<form>` tag.

Down bellow a very easy way to get used to when you're learning Javascript from the begining

```js
function updateText () {
  const inputText = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  const displayText = document.querySelector('#myHeader').innerText = inputText;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myHeader"></h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
  <button onclick="return updateText()" id="button">Enter</button>
</form>
```